# Programmatically adding individual event listeners to multiple divs results in the same function appearing on all affected divs

Tags: javascript, html, url, event-listener

```
for (i = 0;i < cnt;i++) {
    var thumb=thumbnails[i];
    var id=thumb.id;
    thumb.addEventListener('click', function () {
        location.href="SomeWebPage.html?id=" + id;
    }, false);
}
```

The code above results in all thumbnails having the same last `id` assignment instead of individual thumbnail `id` assignments based on the individual `div` `id`'s. My expectation was that each thumbnail `div` would be assigned an event handler that referenced their specific `id` in the `location.href` url being defined. Instead, all of the event handlers have the same url that references just the last `dev` `id`.

Comment: Perhaps try using `let id=thumb.id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **let** instead of **var**

```
let id=thumb.id;
```

var is global stuff, thats why only last value is remained in arrow functions memory